# Invalid factor level with rbind to data frame

Tags: r

I'm new in R and I don't know how exacly adding row in data frame.
I add two vectors:

```
b=c("one","lala",1)
d=c("two","lele",2)
```

I want add this to data.frame called a.

```
a<-rbind(a,b)
```

now I have one correct row

```
      A       B      C
1    one   lala      1
```

next I add

```
a<-rbind(a,d)
```

and result is:

```
      A       B       C
1    one    lala      1
2     NA      NA      NA
```

and console write me warning messages: invalid factor level, NA generated.
What I do wrong or what is better simple way to add new line.
But I don't want in start create full data.frame. I want adding lines.

Comment: You could convert columns of the `data.frame` `a` to `character` then you should be able to `rbind`. Or you can preempt this, when you create `a` perhaps you can use the option `stringsAsFactors=FALSE`

Comment: @user20650 Oh you got right. I put `options(stringsAsFactors=FALSE)` and not work, your `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` work. Thank you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you do

```
c("one","lala",1)
```

this creates a vector of strings.  The `1` is converted to character type,
so that all elements in the vector are the same type.

Then `rbind(a,b)` will try to combine `a` which is a data frame and `b`
which is a character vector and this is not what you want.

The way to do this is using `rbind` with data frame objects.

```
a <- NULL
b <- data.frame(A="one", B="lala", C=1)
d <- data.frame(A="two", B="lele", C=2)

a <- rbind(a, b)
a <- rbind(a, d)
```

Now we can see that the columns in data frame `a` are the proper type.

```
> lapply(a, class)
$A
[1] "factor"

$B
[1] "factor"

$C
[1] "numeric"

>
```

Notice that you must name the columns when you create the different data
frame, otherwise `rbind` will fail.  If you do

```
b <- data.frame("one", "lala", 1)
d <- data.frame("two", "lele", 2)
```

then

```
> rbind(b, d)
Error in match.names(clabs, names(xi)) : 
  names do not match previous names
```

Comment: Oh yes. Problem is vector, not some else.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` to the BOTH the `data.frame()` function and the `rbind()` function.

In some versions of R, but not others, `rbind()` will automatically convert strings to factors.  For example, in R version 3.6.2, `rbind` will do the factor conversion automatically even if the global setting is `options(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)`.  This is not the case in R version 4.0.4, and so `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` does not need to be added to the `rbind()` statement in version 4.0.4.

Answer (score 0):

Just one more point, as i test, for example:
we have a data frame as df, and 6 columns as below, when try to use `rbind` to combine
the 2nd line to the 1st line,

```
df <- data.frame()
df <- rbind(df, row1)
df <- rbind(df, row2)
```

it will happen like this

```
  col1 col2 col3               col4                   col5       col6
1   1   1   Pilot              Greg                Andy Dwyer   95.00
2   1   1   Pilot              Greg                NA           92.00
```

As i test, set `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` not only should happen on initialize `df` dataframe, but also should apply to `rbind` function, after converting to below:

```
df <- data.frame(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df <- rbind(df, row1, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df <- rbind(df, row2, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

it works fine

```
  col1 col2 col3               col4                   col5       col6
1   1   1   Pilot              Greg                Andy Dwyer   95.00
2   1   1   Pilot              Greg                Audi Sier    92.00
```