# Unable to rbind factor

Tags: r

I am unable to rbind when the class of the column is a factor. For example,

```
asd <- data.frame(a = c("A", "B"), b = c("D","S"))
asd$b <- as.factor(asd$b)
```

Above is the dataframe and I am converting one of the columns to factor. When I try below operation, NA is generated. Can we rbind keeping as factor only

```
rbind(asd, c("X","Z"))
  a    b
1 A    D
2 B    S
3 X <NA>
Warning message:
In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, ri, value = "Z") :
  invalid factor level, NA generated
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Invalid factor level with rbind to data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25285570/invalid-factor-level-with-rbind-to-data-frame)

Comment: You are trying to bind a vector to a dataframe. Convert your vector to a dataframe. Then use rbind like `rbind(asd,data.frame(a="X", b="Z"))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have factor column you need to include all the levels that your data can have.

```
levels(asd$b) <- c(levels(asd$b), 'Z')
rbind(asd, c("X","Z"))

#  a b
#1 A D
#2 B S
#3 X Z
```

Answer (score 0):

We could convert to `matrix` and then to `data.frame`

```
asd <- as.data.frame(rbind(as.matrix(asd), c("X", "Z")))
asd$b <- factor(asd$b)
```